# Extract arguments from string with python function

Tags: python, string, function, extract, python-re

I'm looking for a way to extract arguments embedded into python function returned to me as strings.

For example:

```
'create.copy("Node_A", "Information", False)'
# expected return: ["Node_A", "Information", "False"]

'create.new("Node_B")'
# expected return: ["Node_B"]

'delete("Node_C")'
# expected return: ["Node_C"]
```

My first approach was regular expressions like this:

> re.match(r"("(.+?")")

But it returns None all the time.

How can I get list of this arguments?

BTW: I'm forced to use Python 2.7 and only built-in functions :(

Comment: All of your strings would be syntax errors. Please provide valid data and regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here an example without any external modules and totally compatible with python2.7. Slice the string w.r.t. the position of the brackets, clean it from extra white-spaces and split at `,`.

```
f = 'create.copy("Node_A", "Information", False)'
i_open = f.find('(')
i_close = f.find(')')

print(f[i_open+1: i_close].replace(' ', '').split(','))
```

Output

```
['"Node_A"', '"Information"', 'False']
```

Remark:

- not for nested functions.
- the closing bracket can also be found by reversing the string

  `i_close = len(f) - f[::-1].find(')') - 1`

Answer (score 1):

You can parse these expressions using the built-in [ast](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html) module.

```py
import ast

def get_args(expr):
    tree = ast.parse(expr)
    args = tree.body[0].value.args
    
    return [arg.value for arg in args]

get_args('create.copy("Node_A", "Information", False)') # ['Node_A', 'Information', False]
get_args('create.new("Node_B")') # ['Node_B']
get_args('delete("Node_C")') # ['Node_C']
```

Answer (score 0):

See below (tested using python 3.6)

```
def get_args(expr):
    args = expr[expr.find('(') + 1:expr.find(')')].split(',')
    return [x.replace('"', '') for x in args]


entries = ['create.copy("Node_A", "Information", False)', "create.new(\"Node_B\")"]
for entry in entries:
    print(get_args(entry))
```

output

```
   ['Node_A', ' Information', ' False']
   ['Node_B']
```